# How do I set my input shape of an LSTM input layer, my X_train has 2 columns and y_train 1 column

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout

regressor = Sequential()

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences= True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[0],2)))
regressor.add(Dropout(rate = 0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences= True))
regressor.add(Dropout(rate = 0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50))
regressor.add(Dropout(rate = 0.2))

regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))

regressor.compile(optimizer= 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = ['accuracy'])

regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 1000, epochs = 25)'
```

Im trying to predict the value of `y_train` based the the two features of `X_train`

I end up with the error message: `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_3_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (10000, 2)`

Comment: Does input_shape=X_train.shape[-2:], instead of (X_train.shape[0],2) works?

Comment: no it doesn't, same error